# Three.JS: Weird shadow artifacts from a spotlight, but only in Android

Tags: android, three.js, shadow

Using Three.js v0.113.2 I'm rendering this scene of a mug on a plane with two spotlights (one behind, one in front), and an ambient light.  The front spotlight casts shadows, the mug is set to cast shadows (but *not* receive them), and the plane is set to receive shadows.  I'm using a shadow radius of 20 (iirc). The shadow mapSize is 1024x1024.

On Android, and only on Android (this renders correctly on iPhones, Windows, and Mac desktops) I see these weird banding artifacts from the lighting on the objects.  It's most evident on the mug, but it's present on the pane as well.  The artifact has clearly distinguishable lines that do not match up to the geometry of the mug object.

[image]

I have tried setting the `camera.near` and `camera.far` planes to tightly encapsulate the scene, and ended up with 50/200 for those values.  No effect.

I tried setting the `shadow.bias` value to something very near zero, -.001.  Also no effect.

Unfortunately, that was the extent of the suggestions I could find from the Three.js repo and other StackOverflow questions.  If this artifacting looks familiar to anyone, I would love to figure out how to fix this.

**EDIT:** I've set `castShadow` on the Spotlight to `false`, removed the ambient light, removed the `castShadow` and `receiveShadow` from all meshes, and the artifacting still shows up on Android (only).

Comment: I've never seen a negative shadowmap bias. Have you tried something positive, like 0.001? Also, make sure you set `material.side = THREE.FrontSide` because that determines which face casts shadows [as outlined here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.shadowSide) Looks like you might have the faces casting shadows on themselves.

Comment: @Marquizzo I just tried with a positive small bias, setting the `material.side` and the `material.shadowSide` to `THREE.FrontSide` (for all meshes), and still the exact same shadow artifacts appear on both the mug and the plane.  Again, only on Android (all browsers), not on iOS or any Desktop browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone finds this in the future:

The unfortunate artifacting that, at this time, affects only Android, is caused by having the `angle` value of any spotlight set too low.  In the scene above, there was a spotlight with an angle of 0.091.  When that was raised to 0.171 the strange banding disappeared.